# What is best and simple way to debug Node.js on simple task

Tags: node.js, debugging

Simpel task: like Express app or CLI app on local machine

After I try `node-inspector` and that not work very well by now .
and the debugger of `webStorm` stop working properly for me.
and `visual studio code` work some time but the debugger not mature enough like chrome dev tool

what is the best way to debuuger node.js 6.x.x.this day ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually these are private preferences but you can use the [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_V8) from the Chrome Developer Tools to debug Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

on chrome : go to [chrome://inspect](http://chrome://inspect) and click `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`

New windows openning for you and waiting for node application to connect
then in terminal write :

```
node --inspect app.js
```

and that all. the debugger windows attach automatically to the app for debugging. and every time you reset the app debugger windows attach again automatically

have fun